# Find indices of vector NaN/Not NaN

Tags: matlab, octave

In MATLAB, how does one find all the indices of vectors a and b such that for that index a is non-NaN but b is NaN?  I got it to work with a for-loop but I was wondering if there is a vectorized solution.

Comment: `~isnan(a)&isnan(b)`. That returns a [logical index](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2013/02/20/logical-indexing-multiple-conditions/). Apply `find` to it if you prefer integer indexing

Comment: @LuisMendo Sweet! That's perfect. U should post it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
~isnan(a)&isnan(b)
```

That returns a [logical index](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2013/02/20/logical-indexing-multiple-conditions/). Apply `find` to it if you prefer integer indexing.